# Comparing the values of 2 lists without built-ins

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, iteration

I'm trying to make and anagram checker without any built-in functions. So far, I've managed this:

```
def isa1(s1, s2):
    a = s1.lower()
    b = s2.lower()
    c = list(a)
    d = list(b)
    l = len(s1)
    counter = 0
    for i in range(l):
        
        if c[i] == d[0]:
            del d[0]
            counter += 1
        elif c[i] == d[1]:
            del d[1]
            counter += 1
        elif c[i] == d[2]:
            del d[2]
            counter += 1
        elif c[i] == d[3]:
            del d[3]
            counter += 1
        elif c[i] == d[4]:
            del d[4]
            counter += 1
        elif c[i] == d[5]:
            del d[5]
            counter += 1
        else:
            pass
    if counter == len(s1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I'm happy with the start, bar the assignment naming, but I cant figure out how to iterate through my second string, s2, without the for-loop being ridiculous. Plus this code will only work for a string/list 6 characters long.

Sorry if this seems simply, I'm just starting Python and programming in general
Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming you want to not use built ins because you want to learn the language better. The thing about built ins is that they are just functions in the core python library. They didn't use to exist, but since it's such commonly used code, it was beneficial to add them to the core library. So if you really want to not use them, then you will need to build your own helper functions. In this case, I would say a helper to replace `s.find()`. You could do this through a separate loop function.

Comment: Why are you set against using built-in functions, exactly? You do realize that `list()` and `len()` are also built-in functions, right? The 'easy' solution for checking if two lists are anagrams would be `sorted(list1) == sorted(list2)`, since `sorted()` is a built-in function as well, and you will _always_ have access to it, so there's very little reason not to use it when appropriate. Don't think of built-in functions as 'shortcuts' - they're as much a part of the language as the syntax and the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

if you are okay with using for in side of for you can do:

```py
def isa1(s1, s2):
    a = s1.lower()
    b = s2.lower()
    c = list(a)
    d = list(b)
    l = len(s1)
    counter = 0
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(len(d)):
            if c[i] == d[j]:
                del d[j]
                counter += 1
                break  # to continue to the next letter
    if counter == len(s1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

this solution will check against each letter in the second list, and if it finds a match it will break the inner loop going to the next letter.